# JSF2 h:selectOneListBox to render <li> instead of <option>

Tags: jsf-2

We are using JSF2.0 ,our end HTML needs to have `<li>` in the list box instead of `<optionValues>`.  We are using `<h:selectOneListBox>` in the jsf . We are trying to use Jquery to change the `<optionValues>` to `<li>`.

Is there any other bettter solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with the [standard JSF HTML component set](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/). They all renders standard HTML elements without any fanciness.

You need to look at a JSF component library with enhanced skinnability support. The [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) component library for example, which uses jQuery UI under the covers, has a [`<p:selectOneListbox>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneListbox.jsf) which generates an `<ul><li>`, exactly as you need. See the [showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneListbox.jsf). Here's the generated HTML source of the 1st `<p:selectOneListbox>` example on the showcase page:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all">Option 1</li>
    <li class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all ui-state-active">Option 2</li>
    <li class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC ,so do i need to include prime faces library seperately in my project to achive this?

Comment: Yes. Just drop the PrimeFaces JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, declare `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` in the view and replace the `h:` by `p:` in the `<h:selectOneListbox>`. That's all.